# How to send SMS/email when you know the contact id?

Tags: android

When I have the contact id, how do I send an SMS/email (aka text) to it?

I've seen code like this, but none are using the contact it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
act.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to send the text message directly from your app instead of throwing the intent, you can use `sendTextMessage()` in android.telephony.SmsManager, [see the docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html). That does mean a small annoyance for your user, as well as requiring the permission in the manifest.

To do what you are doing above with the phone number filled in, you have to include: `intent.putExtra("address", "07910123456");`

Thus, the completed code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
intent.putExtra("address", "07910123456");
act.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), 0);
```